ImportError: cannot import name "Modal"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Aaaaa\Desktop\boy\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
from disnake import Intents, Modal, TextInputStyle, Embed, ButtonStyle, ActionRow, Button, ui
ImportError: cannot import name 'Modal' from 'disnake' (C:\Users\Aaaaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\disnake_init_.py)
I think I wrote the code without errors, but it won't let me load the required modules from disnake. can anyone explain what the reason is? here is the code:
import disnake
from disnake import Intents, Modal, TextInputStyle, Embed, ButtonStyle, ActionRow, Button, ui
from disnake.ext import commands

intents = Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

# Канал для отправки заявок
APPLICATION_CHANNEL_ID = 1313915216211214476  # Замените на ID Вашего канала
verification_message_id = None

# Эмбед с предложением о верификации
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Мы вошли как {bot.user}')
    channel = bot.get_channel(APPLICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    embed = Embed(title="Верификация", description="Пожалуйста, нажмите кнопку ниже для заполнения формы верификации.")
    global verification_message_id
    verification_message = await channel.send(embed=embed, components=[Button(label="Заполнить форму", style=ButtonStyle.green)])
    verification_message_id = verification_message.id

# Обработка нажатия на кнопку
@bot.component("Заполнить форму")
async def form_button(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    modal = Modal("Форма верификации", timeout=60)
    modal.add_item(disnake.TextInput("Имя", style=TextInputStyle.short))
    modal.add_item(disnake.TextInput("Возраст", style=TextInputStyle.short))
    modal.add_item(disnake.TextInput("Цель прибывания", style=TextInputStyle.paragraph))
    await interaction.send_modal(modal)

# Обработка отправки модального окна
@bot.modal("Форма верификации")
async def handle_modal(modal: Modal, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    username = modal.children[0].value
    age = modal.children[1].value
    purpose = modal.children[2].value

    user = interaction.user
    embed = Embed(title="Новая заявка", description="Заявка на верификацию")
    embed.add_field(name="Имя", value=username)
    embed.add_field(name="Возраст", value=age)
    embed.add_field(name="Цель прибывания", value=purpose)
    embed.add_field(name="ID пользователя", value=user.id)
    embed.add_field(name="Дата создания аккаунта", value=user.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    embed.add_field(name="Дата присоединения к серверу", value=user.joined_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar.url)

    # Отправляем заявку в отдельный канал
    application_channel = bot.get_channel(APPLICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    application_message = await application_channel.send(embed=embed, components=[
        ActionRow(
            Button(label="Принять", style=ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="accept"),
            Button(label="Отклонить", style=ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="decline")
        )
    ])

    # Делаем так, чтобы пользователю отправлялось подтверждение
    await interaction.send("Ваша заявка была отправлена.", ephemeral=True)

# Обработка кнопок принятия и отклонения заявки
@bot.component("accept")
async def accept_button(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    role = disnake.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, name="member")  # Замените на название Вашей роли
    await interaction.user.add_roles(role)
    await interaction.send("Заявка принята. Вы получили роль 'member'.", ephemeral=True)

@bot.component("decline")
async def decline_button(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    await interaction.send("Заявка отклонена.", ephemeral=True)

# Запуск бота
bot.run("TOKEN")  # Замените на токен Вашего бота


I tried reinstalling the disnake library, thinking that maybe reinstalling it would help, but alas(

Based on the documentation it looks either like your imports should include from disnake.ui import Modal OR the import line you currently have should be modifed to get ModalInteraction instead of Modal

The Modal class cannot be imported directly from the disnake module. In disnake the UI components like Modal are located within the disnake.ui submodule. Therefore, you should import Modal from disnake.ui as follows:
from disnake.ui import Modal

Additionally, the TextInput component, which is essential for creating input fields within a modal, is also part of the disnake.ui submodule. You should import it like this:
from disnake.ui import TextInput

Here's the corrected import section of your code:
import disnake
from disnake import Intents, Embed, ButtonStyle, ActionRow, Button
from disnake.ext import commands
from disnake.ui import Modal, TextInput

For more detailed information on creating and handling modals in disnake, you can refer to the official guide https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api/interactions.html#modalinteraction
